# Bulk web scraper which supports login system

Tags: scraping, data

I have a website which has thousands of pages and I need to extract some data from those into a database file. The website has a login. How can I bulk scrape data I need from all of these pages?

There are many programs available online but most of them can't get it done quite right and I don't have the knowledge to code a program or use things like BeautifulSoup.

I would be extremely happy if someone can help me.